# SQL Query to have Children have an equal amount of Toys

Tags: sql, sql-server, algorithm

Trying to figure out the SQL query to balance toys among children.

In the `Children` table the columns are:

```
ID INT, <br>
FNAME NCHAR(50), <br>
LNAME NCHAR(50), <br>
NumberofToys INT
```

Then in the `Toys` table we have:

```
ID INT, <BR>
ToyName NCHAR(50) <BR>
ChildrenID INT -->This is a FK to the Children table
```

So the relationship is one-to-many here (one child can have 0 to many toys).

Balancing the toys among the children would mean the following:

1. If there are n amount of Children and m amount of Toys, then each Child should have (m/n) Toys
2. If there are n amount of Children and n+1 amount of Toys, then each Child would have (m/n) Toys with one child in the table having n+1 toys.
3. If there are n amount of Children and n-1 amount of Toys, then each Child would have (m/n) Toys with one child in the table having n-1 toys.
4. If already balanced and a Child were to be removed from the table then their toys should be evenly distributed one at a time until their share of toys are fully distributed.
5. If already balanced and one of the Child's toys was removed from the Toys table, then the remaining toys in the table should be evenly re-distributed

Sample Set (Pre-balanced):

```
Children
ID    FNAME    LNAME    NumberofToys  

1      Bob      Jones     3
2      Jenny    James     5


Toys
ID    ToyName    ChildrenID
1      Bear       1
2      Train      2
3      Truck      2
4      Car        2
```

Solution Set:

```
Children
ID    FNAME    LNAME    NumberofToys  

1      Bob      Jones      2
2      Jenny     James     2


Toys
ID    ToyName    ChildrenID
1      Bear       1
2      Train      1
3      Truck      2
4      Car        2
```

I can't seem to get the correct algorithm here. Once a toy is added to the Toys table, the FK should be the first Child ID that has the least amount of toys. What I've tried is below:

```
DECLARE @ToyCount INT,
@ID INT
--This should take care of the balancing problem.
--Since Toys get added one at a time, just add to first Child
----with minimum amount of customers
SET @ToyCount = (SELECT MIN(NumberofToys) FROM Children)

--Store top id that has least amount of toys
    SET @ID = (SELECT TOP 1 ID
    FROM Children
    WHERE @ToyCount=NumberofToys)
--This part is if a Child needs to be added to the table, NumberofToys would be originally 0
    INSERT INTO Children (FNAME, LNAME, NumberofToys)
    VALUES(@fname, @lname, 0);


--Increasing the number of toys for the ID we SET above
UPDATE Children
SET NumberofToys = NumberofToys + 1
WHERE ID=@ID
```

The balancing needs to be done if the user manually "unbalances" the number of toys across the children. The section above that does the adding fixes any new toys but not the pre-existing ones. Can someone help me out here please? My attempt at the pre-existing toys is below:

```
DECLARE @ToyCount INT, @ToyCountMAX,
@ID INT, @IDMAX INT, @IDTarget INT

SET @ToyCount = (SELECT MIN(NumberofToys) FROM Children)
SET @ToyCountMAX = (SELECT MAX(NumberofToys) FROM Children)


--Store top id that has least amount of toys
    SET @ID = (SELECT TOP 1 ID
    FROM Children
    WHERE @ToyCount=NumberofToys)
--Store top id that has most amount of toys
SET @IDMAX = (SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM Children WHERE @ToyCountMAX=NumberofToys)

--Take top id that has most amount of toys and set it to an ID that has least amount (I believe my problem is here. Can't get the syntax to set the top ChildrenID to the SELECT...on the right side of the = sign
UPDATE Toys
SET ChildrenID = (SELECT TOP 1 ChildrenID FROM Children WHERE NumberofToys=MIN(NumberofToys)
WHERE ChildrenID=@IDMAX
    --Increasing the number of toys for the ID we SET above
    UPDATE Children
    SET NumberofToys = NumberofToys + 1
    WHERE ID=@ID

--decreasing number of toys for the max ID
UPDATE Children
SET NumberofToys = NumberofToys - 1
WHERE ID=@IDMAX
```

Comment: The line "----with minimum amount of customers" should read as "----with minimum amount of toys"

Comment: Storying both the number of toys with the child and the owner of each toy duplicates data, makes for headaches. Just drop that column from the Children table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the folloing Store Procedure, it should balance `Toys` between `Children` at any stage.

**Note:** When removing a child from `Children` table, you would need to maintain foreign key relationship. Hence,

1. assign that child's toys to any other child in the table
2. then delete the child from table `Children`
3. call store procedure to re-balance

**Store Procedure**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE BalanceToys
AS
BEGIN

    -- While there is imbalance between children
    -- i.e. MAX toys owned minus MIN toys owned is greater than 1
    WHILE((SELECT MAX(cnt)-MIN(cnt) FROM (
        SELECT c.ID, SUM(CASE WHEN t.ID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Cnt
        FROM Children c
            LEFT JOIN Toys t ON c.ID = t.ChildrenID
        GROUP BY c.ID) v) > 1)
    BEGIN

        -- We rebalance 1 toy at a time
        -- the child with most toys will give 1 toy to the child with least toys
        UPDATE TOP (1) Toys
        SET ChildrenID = (SELECT TOP 1 c.ID
            FROM Children c
                LEFT JOIN Toys t ON c.ID = t.ChildrenID
            GROUP BY c.ID
            ORDER BY SUM(CASE WHEN t.ID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))
        WHERE ChildrenID = (SELECT TOP 1 c.ID
            FROM Children c
                LEFT JOIN Toys t ON c.ID = t.ChildrenID
            GROUP BY c.ID
            ORDER BY SUM(CASE WHEN t.ID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) DESC)

       -- Loop until all balanced
    END

    -- Update NumberofToys 
    UPDATE Children
    SET NumberofToys = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Toys WHERE ChildrenID = Children.ID)

END
GO
```